# React Router not recognizing route, redirects me to blank screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am using react router v4, and I register a route and try and make a link to it, but when I click the link or type it in manually it doesn't seem to register the contents and doesn't even recognize the route at all

Here is me registering and making the link

```
<div className="main-contain">
        <Route exact={true} path='/testingroute' component={TestBlock}/>
        <span>Click <Link to={'/testingroute'} className="main-link">here</Link> for further details!</span>
</div>
```

Here is the component that the route is supposed to render

```
const TestBlock = (props) => {
  console.log("this is being called");

  return (
    <span>Test</span>
  );
}
```

The app is wrapped in a `<BrowserRouter>` by the way

Could use some help as I have been trying to get this work for the past few days. Please and thank you

Comment: Works fine for me. You can check here : `https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-stallman-u1h3t`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to wrap your Route component inside a Switch component?

```
<Switch>
  <Route path='/testingroute' component={TestBlock}/>
<Switch>
```

Also i see that you put the attr

```
exact={true}
```

Is there any other route using that attr? You might want to check for that too

Answer (score 0):

A `<Switch>` looks through its children s and the first one that matches the current URL.

So this would do the work.

```
<Switch>
    <Route path='/testingroute' component={TestBlock}/>
<Switch>
```

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start